# AndroidTV Development: Device Catalogue targeting status shows "Not opted in"

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, google-play-console

Recently published an Android TV app on the Play Store where the Device catalog report mentioned all the devices' targeting statuses as "Not opted in" it makes an installation problem, and the app is not listed on the TV Play Store app but available on the Play Store Website.

[image: Reference screenshot of playconsole]

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered this same problem with my Android TV app. It appears that you need to explicitly tag your app as targeting Android TV devices. This is done by going to "Setup > Advanced Settings > Release Types" and clicking "Manage" next to Android TV.

[image: Screenshot of menu location on Google Play Console]

You will then need to upload Android TV-specific screenshots and Google Play banners, and then go through an Android TV-specific review process. Once that is done, your app should be available to Android TV users.